# Determinant arising in a problem from probability

Tags: nt.number-theory, pr.probability, linear-algebra, determinants

Consider the determinant:
$$\Delta:=
\left|\begin{array}{cccc}
A_{j_1} & A_{k_1} & A_{j_1}A_{k_1} & 1 \\
A_{j_2} & A_{k_2} & A_{j_2}A_{k_2} & 1 \\
A_{j_3  } & A_{k_3  } & A_{j_3  }A_{k_3  } & 1 \\
A_{j_4} & A_{k_4} & A_{j_4 }A_{k_4 } & 1 \\
\end{array}\right| .
$$
where
$$A_{k}:=\frac{3^k-1}{3^k-2^k}, \;k\in N.$$

Question. For which points $(j_1,...,j_4,k_1,...k_4)\in N^8$
this determinant $\Delta$ is different from zero?

Background. If $X,Y$ are two probability distributions, one
is interested in their "uncorrelatedness set",
$$U:=\{(j,k)\in N^2: E(X^jY^k)=E(X^j)E(Y^k)\}.$$
The question arises in the investigation of uncorrelatedness set
of two uniform distributions on a set of three elements.

Comment: I don't know if a complete characterization is possible.  I suppose you are aware of cases where the determinant is $0$ without considering the particular form of $A_j$, e.g. if two rows are equal or two columns are equal or (slightly less trivially) if $(k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4)$ is a permutation of $(j_1,j_2,j_3,j_4)$ consisting of two disjoint transpositions.

Comment: ... or if $j_1=j_2$ and $k_3=k_4$.

Comment: @Robert Israel Thank you for your interest. Yes, I have found these conditions. Regrettalbly, I was unabe to find any sufficient condition for the determinant to be different from 0.

Comment: I would typeset this question as:  When is  $$
\left|\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & f(a) & f(a') & f(a)f(a') \\
1 & f(b) & f(b') & f(b)f(b') \\
1 & f(c) & f(c') & f(c)f(c') \\
1 & f(d) & f(d') & f(d)f(d') \\
\end{array}\right| \neq 0
$$
where $f(x)=(3^x-1)/(3^x-2^x)$?  This avoids the capital letters that suggest submatrices and the distracting double subscripts.